# Can this embedding to double dual EPW sextic happen?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hyperkaehler

Let $\widetilde{Y}_{A^{\perp}}$ denote the double dual EPW sextic defined by the Lagrange subspace $A\subset \bigwedge^3V_6$. If $A$ is very general, then $\widetilde{Y}_{A^{\perp}}$ is a smooth hyperKahler fourfold.
Let $\widetilde{Y}^{\geq 2}_{A}$ be the double EPW sextic surface defined by $A$. Is it possible that there is an embedding $\widetilde{Y}^{\geq 2}_{A}\hookrightarrow \widetilde{Y}_{A^{\perp}}$? I expect that there should not exist such embedding. We know that there is a  natural embedding $Y^{\geq 2}_{A^{\perp}}\subset Y_{A^{\perp}}$ by definition.